# Why quantum computing companies use superconducting qubits?

Tags: superconductivity, quantum-computer

Why are superconducting qubits superior to other types of experimental realisation of qubits? I assume this because Dwave, IBM, rigetti among other companies in the quantum computing business use superconducting qubits.

Comment: This would be a good question for [SE.QuantumComputing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Not all do. See e.g. [Xanadu](https://www.xanadu.ai/), aimed at optical quantum computing, or Microsoft research, striving to realize topological quantum computation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time scale $\tau$ scale for decoherence usually goes like some power of the temperature $T$. E.g., for a free electron undergoing Thomson scattering by blackbody radiation, $\tau\propto T^{-5}$. This suggests that you want the temperature as low as possible. In general, an ultra-low-temperature electronic device is probably going to be superconducting, both because nonzero resistance would create heat and because many materials happen to become superconducting at very low temperatures.